# How to set MacOS Screen Time Passcode using terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, terminal

As an exercise in terminal (and perhaps other programming languages such as Python), I am trying to accomplish the following task. (My machine is MacOS Version 10.15.7, if that matters.)

**Task.** Create a program that:

1. Sets the Screen Time Passcode to a random 4 digit number everyday at a fixed time (say midnight).
2. Generates a plain text file in a preset location containing the 4 digit number.

**My question.** How does one accomplish step 1? In particular, how can one use terminal to set the Screen Time Passcode to a given 4 digit number?

**What I have done so far.**

1. Google searching with obvious queries. (e.g. "How to set MacOS Screen Time Passcode using terminal?")
2. Step 2 of the ask.
3. Executing code at the same time every day. (One should be able to accomplish this using Python or C.)

Comment: Hey, Stackoverflow have some guidelines for new users. And we usually do not entertain homework type questions. Please go through them [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: And for homework questions: [how-to-ask-homework-questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @xcodz-dot By "exercise", I only meant that I am doing this to help me have a better understanding of terminal. (In particular, I am not doing this for some class.) I only want to know if steps 1 and 2 are possible at all (so that I don't have to go on a wild goose chase), and if so, some hints on how to accomplish it.

Comment: Oh, my bad. And by homework question it is not meant its actual homework. As how-to-ask points out, some research work is required from your side

Comment: @xcodz-dot In response to your comment, I narrowed down my question in addition to writing out what I have been able to do myself.

Comment: Ok, I am not gonna say much now. Happy Coding!

Comment: I suggest you split your question into two (1 & 3).  Re 1: https://screentimeapi.com/screen-time-api might be searching point for your search.  Re 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html or https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html depending on if you want a long-running process, or only run the process as needed (I would suggest the latter).